# How can i close Morden UI page with code?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

here on Button click to close mordenwindow..thats doesn't work

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     // this MainWindow is like this  --> <mui:ModernWindow  x:Class="FirstFloor.ModernUI.App.MainWindow1" ....>

        MainWindow1 mw = new MainWindow1();

        // this is my  login Page..
        Login lg = new Login();
        lg.Show();
        mw.Close();  //here code is not working
    }
```

Comment: This looks like you are create a new instance of MainWindow1 here and expecting to close the window which is now shown till now.

Comment: here i want to logoff from MainWindow1 and redirect to Login.xaml..than what should I do?

Comment: you have not shown window by calling `mw.show()` then how are you closing?

Comment: from app.xaml ...its open...

Comment: @Krunalsinh: Could you post the block of code which demonstrate that where the button_click is method is present. if this Button_Click_1(...) method is in your mainwindow1 codebehind, then simply you can use this.close().

Comment: simple Quetion I ask.... how can I close ModernWindow from other page by code??

Comment: To close ModernWindow from other page you need actual object of ModernWindow in other page which is closing form on button click. As per you code in question you are just creating new object of MainWindow1 and calling close method without show. To close ModernWindow you need actual object via ModeenWindow shown/Opened.

Answer (score 0):

What you did in that `Button_Click_1` event is you created a new ModernWindow1 then you closed that newly created `ModernWindow1`, . Now, you technically have two ModernWindow1 in the start of that event. What you need is to close the currently running `ModernWindow1`, and not the newly created `ModernWindow1`. to do that, you need to reference the old `ModernWindow1` before going to another window.

This is the Second ModernWindow

```
public partial class ModernWindow2 : ModernWindow
    {
        public dynamic ReferencedWindow2; //you will put the original Window here

        public ModernWindow2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ModernWindow2(dynamic referencedWindow) // second constructor with a parameter
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReferencedWindow2 = referencedWindow; // the original modernwindow being put in here
        }

        private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReferencedWindow2.Close();
        }
    }
```

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL OR PRIMARY MODERNWINDOW

```
public partial class ModernWindow1 : ModernWindow 
    {

        public ModernWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
            this will show the second modernwindow using the second constructor with parameter
            */
            ModernWindow2 newWindow2 = new ModernWindow2(this);  
            newWindow2.Show();
        }
    }
```